# Spring MVC - 405 Method Not Supported on PUT

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm a little confused on an issue I'm facing where I repeatedly get 405 Method Not Allowed when updating a User object. However the controller code and HTML forms appear to be correct. If I change RequestMethod.PUT to RequestMethod.POST it works fine. Am I missing something here?

I am using the following URL scheme

```
/user [GET] - user list
/user/new [GET] - form to create a new user
/user [POST] - create user
/user/{id}/edit [GET] - form to edit user
/user/{id} [PUT] - update the user
/user/{id} [DELETE] - delete the user
```

HTTP Traffic captured from HTTPFox

Request Header

```
(Request-Line)  POST /searchtool/user/12 HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer http://localhost:8080/searchtool/user/12/edit
Cookie  JSESSIONID=685471429B1BC65305E2B0390F91CBC1
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length  128
```

Response Header

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow   DELETE, PUT
Content-Type    text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language    en-US
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Tue, 27 May 2014 16:01:01 GMT
```

POST Data

```
_method PUT
id  12
firstName   User
lastName    Test
email   test@test.com
userName    test1
password    
password-confirm    
role    2
```

Controller Snippet

```
@Secured(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public String userUpdate(User user, BindingResult userBinding, Model model, @PathVariable long id) {

    if (userBinding.hasErrors()) {
        return (String.format("user/{%s}/edit", String.valueOf(user.getId())));
    }

    try {
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to update user", e);
    }

    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <spring:bind path="user.*">
            <c:if test="${status.errors.errorCount > 0}">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <p>Error: Unable to create user, please see the highlighted fields below.</p>
                </div>
            </c:if>
        </spring:bind>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        <h3>User - Add</h3>
        <br>

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${user.id > 0}">
                <c:set var="formMethod" value="PUT" />
                <c:url var="formAction" value="/user/${user.id}" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:set var="formMethod" value="POST" />
                <c:url var="formAction" value="/user" />
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

        <sf:form method="${formMethod}" action="${formAction}" commandName="user">
            <sf:hidden path="id" id="user-id" /> 
            <spring:bind path="user.firstName">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                    <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="first-name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="user.lastName">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                    <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="last-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="user.email">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="user.userName">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user-name">Username</label>
                    <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="user-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <spring:bind path="user.password">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <sf:password path="${status.expression}" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password-confirm" id="confirm-password" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
            </div>
            <spring:bind path="user.role">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="role">Role</label>
                    <sf:select path="${status.expression}" id="role" class="form-control" >
                        <sf:options items="${roles}" itemLabel="friendlyName" itemValue="id"/>
                    </sf:select>
                    <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                </div>
            </spring:bind>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </sf:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some browsers don't support PUT for forms.

Comment: Including the latest versions of IE and FireFox?

Comment: Looks like... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-in-html-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html) in your web.xml see below.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenmethodfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenmethodfilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatchers-name</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And use Spring tld form tags in your html/jsp and include **_method=PUT** in your form.

Comment: Yes I was missing that snippet in the web.xml file. Thanks!